# Xonar u7 no headphones?

Tags: sound, headphones

I've just bought the Asus Xonar u7 USB audio card. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked fine out of the box with the speakers, but when I switch to headphones (from the knob on the card itself) the audio is still played from the speakers and not from the headphones. In the sound settings I see Xonar U7 Analog surround 5.1 and Digital Output (S/PDIF) Xonar U7 and no headphones. Does anyone know how to make the headphones work?